# Some standard commands freeze on remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, freeze, sh

I'm using a remote machine (ssh connection), and some commands suddenly stopped working.
By that I mean that I enter them and nothing happens: they just kind of freeze, without any output and without finishing the execution.

Commands which work:

```
top, bc, nvidia-smi, sh, vim ~/.bashrc
```

Commands which don't:

```
python, python2, python3 (regardless of arguments), source ~/.bashrc
```

The commands can be killed with Ctrl+C, aside from `python2`, which can't be killed even with Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+D. Also, if I start `tmux`, then for every new pane, I don't see a standard prompt and I can't type commands. It fixes after Ctrl+C.

There are plenty of memory and CPU available (I can see this in `top`).
There were no logouts between working and not-working state. All I did was running some tensorflow models (but they are hand-written, so maybe I could mess up something, but I have no idea what).
Just in case, the system is Ubuntu, and I'm also using Anaconda.

I tried to logout, it didn't help. I can't restart the machine (there are other people using it, and I suspect that I just can't).

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried strace/ltrace those non-working commands? It sounds like a pretty weird issue, especially the .bashrc one.

Comment: @Moreaki, sorry, can't reproduce anymore

Answer (score 0):

There can't be a "turnkey" answer for this sort of thing.

The only times I encountered this kind of thing, was on servers with a wifi connection, where the module went to sleep (energy saving)

Here you seem to see that this is only for use around python.

The first thing to do is to control the use of server resources (top / htop etc ...), to consult your different logs (/ var / log)
... and find out if the problem also exists for other users.

- To know if it is a problem of "connection"
- Know if it is linked to your server (do you have the same concerns elsewhere)
- Know if it is related to your activity (python usage)
- ...

This kind of problem can come from multiple reasons, it is necessary that you rule out the various possible sources.

If you are doing python development, I "sense" a problem in some scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure (and I don't understand why it matters), but it seems the issue was that I've created too many processes (I created a bunch of subprocesses, and maybe I didn't properly killed them or something). Killing all my processes with `pkill -U` seemed to work.